# Merging with UnityYAMLmerge

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, version-control, yaml, atlassian-sourcetree

I followed the instructions here: [Setting up SourceTree to merge unity3d scenes with UnityYAMLMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566436/setting-up-sourcetree-to-merge-unity3d-scenes-with-unityyamlmerge)

But every time I pull, I get a lot of files with conflicts:

[image]

and for each of them I need to launch the external tool which doesn't show anything and after I close it the conflict is resolved:

[image]
[image]

This is unbearably annoying, should I even care about those zero name files?

And why Meld is unable to open any of those files?

Edit: I added the Library folder to my gitignore and now have less conflicted files, but Meld still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the files under `Library/` folder shouldn’t be add to version control by git, the `Asset/Scenes/MainScene.unity.orig` and `Asset/Scenes/MainScene.unity.orig.orig` also shouldn’t add in git to version control since the file `Asset/Scenes/MainScene.unity` is the right one to  be managed in git.

And why does the file `filename.orig` created, it’s mainly caused by the setting for External Merge Tool is not specified correctly in SourceTree. So please check the [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is installed correctly and the requirements are also prepared:

> ```
> Requirements
> • Python 3.3
> • GTK+ 3.14
> • GLib 2.36
> • PyGObject 3.14
> • GtkSourceView 3.14
> • pycairo
> ```

Besides, you can also refer [Unity, SourceTree and Merge Conflicts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQB-N-ClO9g) for the entire settings.